# Google Hangout simpleHangoutApp.xml

Tags: google-plus, google-hangouts

I am seeing the Google Hangout Documentation, and I tried to make work the Getting Started example https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/getting-started, I follow the steps, I downloaded the simpleHangoutApp.xml file and for server I started one in my computer with python(I am using arch linux) I started the server with the line console:

python -m http.server 8000

resulting in this:

Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8000

I think my server is working ok, when follow the step 2 of the above link I do not have problem, in the step 3 in the url I put IP:8000/simpleHangoutApp.xml, IP obviously is my IP, then I save and start the hangout, then is when come the problems, in the center of the hangout screen appear the next:

```
               There was an error loading the application.
```

This application failed to start because it has not provided the required information.

I think the problem could something related with my server because I tried with the example url:

https://plushangoutstarter.appspot.com/static/simpleHangoutApp.xml

And the example works excelent, please if somebody has suggestions I would be very thankful, I am trying to adapt an utility with a Hangout and I need to develop something, but if I can connect at least, I think I am stuck.

Answer (score 1):

There are two likely causes to this problem:

1. The IP address you provided is not one that is globally accessible. This may be the case if you are using a privately routed IP address (most commonly those that start with 192.168, although some others are possible), and this is quite common if you are using a home router.
2. Port 8000 on your machine isn't globally accessible for other reasons - most likely a network or machine firewall. Many ISPs block port 8000 to prevent people from running private web servers.

Both of these cause problems because Google's servers need to be able to get to the file to load it, and appear to be unable to do so.

In either case, the easiest way to test if this is the problem is to try and connect to that port from a machine outside the network.

The solution is also highly dependent on your network configuration and what is available. Many routers can do port forwarding, which will allow people to connect to a port on your public IP addrsess, and be forwarded to a (possibly different) port on a machine with the internal IP address. Consult your router manual for details.

Comment: Ok, well for location reasons is difficult to me test out of my job network, do you have any suggestion for mounting a web server to test the hangout? I don't care if is locally or maybe in some site for file hosting, I just want to make the example work for developing my tentative application. Thank you for your help.

Comment: If you're just looking to get started and test out some static xml, html, and javascript, you can use Google Drive to publicly host the files. See https://googledrive.com/host/0B716ywBKT84AMXBENXlnYmJISlE/GoogleDriveHosting.html

Comment: THank you, I finished using google hosting https://code.google.com/hosting/   It works well, but thank you for your suggestions, I will have in account for future works.